# Django concat F function with character

Tags: django, python-3.6, django-orm, django-database

I have a model which has `group_id` `CharField`. This field should equal object's `pk` with '#' prefix.

I'm trying to update database in such way.

```
MyModel.objects.update(group_id=f'#{F("pk")}')
```

But this doesn't work. In fact, it sets `'#F(pk)'` string for all objects.

Can I do this operation using `F` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make use of the [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) function:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

MyModel.objects.update(group_id=Concat(Value('#'), F('pk')))
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
UPDATE app_mymodel
SET group_id = CONCAT_WS('', '#', app_mymodel.pk)
```

(well locally I got this query, but it can depend on the backend, etc.)

The `_WS` here means "with separator", but since the separator is empty, there is no difference compared with a "simple" concat.

Note that of course `group_id` here should have a type (probably `CharField` that can accept the values generated with this expression).